# Linq: join the results in a IEnumerable<string > to a single string

Tags: linq

how do i join the results in a IEnumerable to a single string?
the IEnumerable contains 20 single letters, and  i want it to combine it to a single string.

And out of curiousity: how would i join it with a separator, for example if the IEnumerable contains the strings a b c d e how can i join it to a,b,c,d,e?

Michel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<string> letters = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
string separator = ", ";
string withSeparator = String.Join(separator, letters.ToArray());
string withoutSeparator = String.Join(String.Empty, letters.ToArray());
```

Also, with 4.0 .NET there's a new simpler overload available: [`String.Join Method (String, IEnumerable<String>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) so you can skip the `ToArray()` call.